# printf is behaving in different ways...and taking address as well as value....address of string and for a pointer only after dereferencing

Tags: c

`printf` is taking address of string and not taking after dereferencing, whereas in case of pointer it is required to dereference.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char str[100];
    int i;
    int j=0;
    int *p;

    p=&j;
    scanf("%s",str);
    for(i=0;str[i];i++)
    {
        if((str[i]>='A') && (str[i]<='Z'))
        {
            str[i]=str[i]+('a'-'A');
        }
        else
        {
            str[i]=str[i]-('a'-'A');
        }
    }
    printf("%s",str);   //it should have been printf("%s",*str); here we are  passing address
    printf("%d\n",j);
    printf("%d",*p);    //here we are passing evact value;

    return 0;
}
```

when used with `*` it crashes and if only `str` is used it works fine...

Comment: char str[100] is a pointer. You do not want to dereference it. You can (I don't say you should) switch between the array / pointer syntax on the same variable.

Comment: @petrch An array and a pointer are **not** the same.  One can decay to the other, but they are distinct.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `%s` format specifier to `printf` is used to print a string and expects a `char *` argument which points to the first element of a null-terminated character array.  The `%d` format specifier is used to print an integer in decimal format and expects an `int`.

Since `str` is an array, when used in an expression it *decays* into a pointer to its first element.  So `str` in an expression has type `char *`, which matches what `%s` expects.

`*str` is not valid for `%s` because that has type `char` and has a value of the first character in an array.  Using the wrong format specifier for a given argument to `printf` invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

`*p` is valid for `%d` because `p` has type `int *`, meaning that `*p` has type `int`, which matches what `%d` expects.

Comment: and in case of  "*p" it is taking value..!!  in case of string it is expecting char * and in case of "p" it is expecting "int" why not address..

Comment: so basically in "scanf" we always take input as "addressof" and in case of "printf" it will depend upon the "type of specifier"(%d or %s and so on)

Comment: @dbush well you wrote in the comment that char str[100] is not a pointer, but it "decays" to it. I guess you maybe referring to some abstract definition, but from the practical standpoint if you do printf("%c:%c",str[0],*(str+0)) you will get exactly the same result including the interpretation in the assembler. Also char * can point anywhere, you can point to an array of integers or any place in the memory and interpret the location as a string if you want to.

Comment: @petrch Section 6.3.2.1 of the [C standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf):  *"Except  when  it  is  the  operand  of  the
sizeof
operator, the
_Alignof
operator, or t
he
unary
&
operator, or is a string  literal  used  to  initialize  an  array, an expression  that  has
type ‘‘array of
type
’’ is converted to an expression with type ‘‘pointer to
type
’’  that  points
to  the  initial  element  of  the  array  object  and  is  not  an  lvalue."*

Comment: @petrch You *could* point a `char *` to some other object and treat it as a string, but you can't expect the result to be consistent.

Comment: Consistent among what? E.g. among platforms and/or compilers or where? Can you give an example?

Comment: @petrch If you point a `char *` to an `int` in an attempt to print it as a string, you'll get different output depending on the byte ordering (big/little endian) or character encoding (ASCII, EBCDIC), and undefined behavior if the representation doesn't contain a byte with 0.

Comment: Yes, that's a common sense. Like you need to understand what is going on on the memory/assembly level before you jump into this, but assuming you know what you are doing, I think it is reasonably predictable.